# Handle mousein and mouseout event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am looking for creating a custom component using Lightning Web Components. I want to be able to detect when the user is taking mouse outside of the element so that I can close the dialog and/or clear the text.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the base component you are using, you can use the focus/blur or mouse in/out events of the component.

You can also use global html events since LWCs support them. [onmouseleave event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseleave)